# How to invoke child function in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I need to invoke a child function named toggle() which is placed in a 'my-app' component (my-app is the child component).
How to invoke this function from parent component?

Child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './my-app.component.html'
})
export class MyAppComponentimplements OnInit, OnChanges {
toggle()
{
//1.load data from data storage if not exist (this was cut out, to simplify code)
this.visible = !this.visible
}
}
```

Parent html code:

```
<a *ngIf="hasValue()" (click) = "toggle()?"></a> // I would like to invoke toggle() function when <a> element is clicked.
<my-app></my-app>
```

Is there any way to call this function? Either by delegate or something?

Comment: In general, you don't. Data flows down to children, actions flow up to parents. If you need anything else, consider a service.

Comment: It's possible, but generally not a good idea. All you need here is a boolean input in the child component, passed by the parent.

Comment: toggle function checks if @input LazyLoad is set to true or not.

if yes then loads data from local storage instead of database

generally I could use another @ input &#39;visible&#39; in my-app component, but i dont know how to detect when visible was changed

Comment: Use a setter decorated with `@Input`, or use ngOnChanges. Both are described here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by getting a reference to the child component in your parent component.

```html
<a *ngIf="hasValue()" (click)="myApp.toggle()"></a>
<my-app #myApp></my-app>
```

Comment: I suspect `my-app` is a root component here

Comment: As a note, you don't need to set up the `ViewChild` reference in your component TypeScript code if you are only going to use the reference in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Raise boolean event from your child to parent (through `@Output()`) and in that event handler in parent do what you want (including calling `toggle()`).

Comment: Your solution works if the event occurs in the child component, and a method of the parent component is to be executed. The problem in the question is the opposite: how to call a method of the child component when an event occurs in the parent component. (Note: I am not the downvoter)

Comment: as his template code shows, he wants to invoke function in parent when child is clicked. thats exactly what i am describing.

Comment: @deezg no. You need to read the question. When the link, in the parent, is clicked, he wants to invoke a method of the child.

Comment: Exactly, I described it poorly. I screwed up :<
But thanks anyway!

Comment: oh, now i understand. he actually wants to invoke method on sibling. yes, i understood wrong. thanks for pointing it out!;)